# Opening a html page and rewriting its content

Tags: javascript

how do I open an existing html page and rewrite its content? This is not working:

```
var left = (screen.width / 2) - 200;
var top = (screen.height / 2) - 200;
var win = window.open("http://someexistinurl.com/embed.html","_blank","width=400,height=400,status=1,resizeable=1,top="+top+ ",left="+left);
win.document.open("text/html", "replace");
win.document.write("<center>Error</center>");
win.document.close();
win.focus();
return win.document.body;
```

Comment: You cannot do this. The best you can do is get the page contents using an ajax request, change what you want, then render it into an iframe. But this is not recommended.

Comment: This actually looks like you're running into the _same origin policy_ because that you're defining a domain suggests it's different to the domain opening it.

Comment: the main goal of this should be, that the new window should be oppened in another policy as the domain window, is it possible somehow?